# My vs code will flicker when I save. I turned on black and flake8 and formatonSave. Why does it flicker? How to stop it?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have the following workspace settings for my Django project in VSCODE.

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "/Users/kim/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python3.7",
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/.classpath": true,
            "**/.project": true,
            "**/.settings": true,
            "**/.factorypath": true
        },
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "[javascript]": {
            "editor.tabSize": 2
        },
        "[json]": {
            "editor.tabSize": 2
        },
        "[markdown]": {
            "editor.tabSize": 2
        },
        "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyParenthesis": true,
        "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--enable=unused-import", "--enable=W0614"],
        "python.formatting.provider": "black",
        "[python]": {
            "editor.formatOnSave": true,
            "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
                "source.organizeImports": true
            }
        },
        "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
}
```

You can see how it flickers as I press Cmd+S to save the file. From this gif

[image]

Why does this flickering happen? I can understand if it happens once. But it will flicker back and forth. As if vscode is formatting on save between two different formats and cannot make its mind.

How do I properly solve this issue?

Comment: What is your VS Code version? And have you checked the Output > Python tab for any "weird" messages? AFAIK, only black has an effect on formatOnSave, while flake8 results should only appear in the Problems tab (since it's a linter, not a formatter).

Comment: Solved it. You can check the github link here for reason and suggested solutions https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6933#issuecomment-543059396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realized I found the issue and solution.

Basically the issue is that there are two formatters used to sort the imports.

I use the answer in this github comment

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6933#issuecomment-543059396

```
        "[python]": {
            "editor.formatOnSave": true,
            "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
                "source.organizeImports.python": true
            }
        },
        "python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--line-length", "88"],
        "python.sortImports.args": [
            "--multi-line=3",
            "--trailing-comma",
            "--force-grid-wrap=0",
            "--use-parentheses",
            "--line-width=88",
        ],
```

Notice I change the organizeImports to organizeImports.python.
Also I added a `"python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--line-length", "88"]`. This is to be consistent with the line-length.

It was suggested in another issue for the same problem. I tried that alone but didn't work. So I combined that with the sortImports args

Comment: I'm curious to experiment with this as I as well prefer trailing commas and parentheses for imports. However, I cannot make it behave: I use Black as well but for my life I don't know what extension I have to deal with sorting imports, as I currently have two options in my command palette: "Organize Imports" and "Python Refactor: Sort Imports"

Comment: is this a question for me? I cannot help you directly. I can only say what works for me. Perhaps it would be better if you can write your own question for other people to help.

Comment: Well actually I only wanted to know what formatter/extension for organizing your imports you have to use these settings.

Comment: Black and flake8. It’s in the title of question. My workspace settings in the question content. The changes to the settings in my answer.